# How to send request parameters with whitespace through a feign client (ApacheHttpClient) to odata

Tags: java, spring-boot, odata, spring-cloud-feign

I want to send GET request via odata with $filter parameter (`$filter=cast(Договор_Key,'Catalog_Договоры') eq guid'<UUID>'`). As you see, there are two whitespaces in the url.
On logs feign shows url: https://mysite/odata/standard.odata/Document_%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9?%24format=json%3Bodata%3Dnometadata&%24inlinecount=allpages&%24filter=cast%28%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80_Key%2C%27Catalog_%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%27%29%20eq%20guid%27e1004688-92d7-11ed-8f65-005056992589%27

This URL works properly on firefox, but my java application throws an error:

```
feign.FeignException$InternalServerError: [500 Internal server error] during [GET] to [https://mysite/odata/standard.odata/Document_%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9?%24format=json%3Bodata%3Dnometadata&%24inlinecount=allpages&%24filter=cast%28%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80_Key%2C%27Catalog_%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%27%29%20eq%20guid%27e1004688-92d7-11ed-8f65-005056992589%27] [OdataClient#getTaxInvoiceByContractId(String,String,String,String)]: [{
"odata.error": {
"code": "-1",
"message": {
"lang": "ru",
"value": "{(3, 2)}: Операция не разрешена в предложении \"ГДЕ\"\n<<?>>CAST( sourceAlias.Договор AS Catalog.Договоры )"
}
}
```

}]

I don't understand, why it works on browser, but not in my application.

I'm using:
`SpringBoot 3.0.5`, `spring-cloud-starter-openfeign 4.0.1`, `io.github.openfeign.feign-httpclient 12.2`.

Feign config class. I've customized my Feign client to disable SSL, therefore `io.github.openfeign.feign-httpclient 12.2` dependency was added.

```
import feign.Feign;
import feign.Logger;
import feign.httpclient.ApacheHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public ApacheHttpClient apacheFeignClient() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }}, new SecureRandom());

        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE;

        return new ApacheHttpClient(HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                .setSSLHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier)
                .build());
    }

    @Bean
    public Feign.Builder feignBuilder() throws Exception {
        return Feign.builder()
                .client(apacheFeignClient());
    }

    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.BASIC;
    }
}
```

My feign client class:

```
package ru.rcitsakha.bitrixapi.client;

import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import ru.rcitsakha.bitrixapi.config.FeignClientConfig;

@FeignClient(name = "odataClient", url = "${odata.url}", configuration = FeignClientConfig.class)
public interface OdataClient {

    // other endpoints with cirillic alphabet, but without whitespaces works fine

    // these endpoints with whitespaces doesn't work
    @GetMapping("/Document_СчетФактураВыданный")
    String getTaxInvoiceByContractId(
            @RequestHeader("Authorization") String token,
            @RequestParam("$format") String format,
            @RequestParam("$inlinecount") String inlineCount,
            @RequestParam("$filter") String contractId);
}
```

My repository class where the problematic request ($filter) is formed

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import ru.rcitsakha.bitrixapi.client.OdataClient;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
public class OdataRepository {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;
    private final OdataClient odataClient;

    @Value("${odata.responseFormat}")
    private String responseFormat;
    @Value("${odata.inlineCount}")
    private String inlineCount;
    @Value("${odata.auth_token}")
    private String token;

    public JsonNode getTaxInvoiceByContractId(String contractId) {
        JsonNode node = null;
        String filterRequest = "cast(Договор_Key,'Catalog_Договоры') eq guid'" + contractId + "'";
        String responseData = odataClient.getTaxInvoiceByContractId(token, responseFormat, inlineCount, filterRequest);
        try {
            node = mapper.readTree(responseData);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Object mapper could not read tree");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return node;
    }
}
```

PS:
Advices, that didn't help me:

1. URLEncoder.encode
2. replaceAll " " by "%20"
3. RequestInterceptor that replaceAll " " by "%20"
4. @QueryMap instead of @RequestParam("$filter") String contractId

Comment: You need to look in your server logs and find the exception which is occuring there.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have permissions to see logs of odata server

Comment: You cannot have white spaces in an http url, all white spaces must be url encoder, some browsers or servers will automatically convert white space to %20 url encoder others will throw an error.

Comment: According to feign logs, it properly encoding whitespace to %20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing ApacheHttpClient with OkHttpClient `io.github.openfeign:feign-okhttp:12.2` and Builder with `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0` helped.

```
import feign.Feign;
import feign.Logger;
import feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public OkHttpClient okHttpClient() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }};

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());

        Builder builder = new Builder();
        builder.sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);
        builder.hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true);
        return new feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient(builder.build());
    }

    @Bean
    public Feign.Builder feignBuilder(ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> converters) throws Exception {
        return Feign.builder()
                .client(okHttpClient());
    }

    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.HEADERS;
    }
}
```

I think ApacheHttpClient internally replaces spaces with '+'.